# Device not booting after factory reset

Tags: factory-reset, boot

My problems is my phone keep showing 'ANDROID' after I'm resetting it.

I tried to restart but it keep showing the same.

What can I do?

Comment: Have you tried taking out the battery, and keeping it out for about a minute before placing it back?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your phone there could an option for a "hard" factory reset. This is usually done through a combination of key press just after turning the device ON so it does not require the OS to start.

I would suggest you to google "hard factory reset" with the name of your device to find more information.